# Ctrl-E in Vimscript string within `exec "norm! "...`

Tags: string, vim, escaping

I want to use [Ctrl-E to scroll](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html) some (here 10) lines down. I want this in usual `exec "norm! ...` mapping like so

```
nnoremap <leader>e :<C-U>exec "norm! 10\<C-E>"<CR>
nnoremap <leader>y :<C-U>exec "norm! 10\<C-Y>"<CR>
```

If press `<leader>y` everything works as expected (I scroll 10 lines up). But if I press `<leader>e` I get the following error (and expected it to scroll 10 lines down):

```
E114: Missing quote: "norm! 10\"
E15: Invalid expression: "norm! 10\"
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Does anyone know how I can fix that?

Edit: The reason I am building a string and executing it is so that I can calculate the number of lines scrolled with an expression (here `f()`).

```
nnoremap <leader>e :<C-U>exec "norm! ". f() ." \<C-E>"<CR>
```

Comment: Why not `nnoremap <leader>e 10<C-E>`?

Comment: @romainl Good point. I edited the post to reflect that I actually want more. I was panning to make a separate question with the actual problem I was having. (Not sure If that's how I should do it and I'm still interested in this exact question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
nnoremap <leader>e :<C-u>exec "norm! 10<C-v><C-e>"<CR>
nnoremap <leader>y :<C-u>exec "norm! 10<C-v><C-y>"<CR>
```